# When should I define CSS class selectors inside other class selector definitions?

Tags: css

EDIT 1
Based on suggestions, I tried this:

```
.lower-container {
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 92vw;
//    height: 46vh; <--- no height defined

/* nested for adding classes to change position and height of lower-container */
    .lower-container.lower-full {
      height: 92vh;
      top: 0;
    }

    .lower-container.lower-mid {
      height: 46vh;
      top: 46vh;
    }

    .lower-container.lower-closed {
      height: 1vh;
      top: 91vh;
    }
}
```

In the Elements Panel I see:
[image]

But in the Styles panel I have:
[image]

So although I'm applying the additional class, the height is not getting set, and the additional class isn't showing in the styles.

---

Original question
I'm defining some classes inside of others like this:

```
.lower-container {
    height: 46vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    ...

    .lower-full {
        height: 92vh;
    }
}
```

Then when it comes time to change the height I'm doing:

```
    lowerContainerElement.classList.add('lower-full')
```

But on the console, the element doesn't have the .lower-full style in the Styles panel,
even though in the Elements panel it shows class="{other classes} lower-full"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CSS by itself does not have nested definitions.  You are probably looking at some SASS or LESS file that will be pre-processed before deployment as those were created to overcome this (and other) shortcoming of CSS

Comment: @blurfus sorry I'm using SASS / .scss files yes. But still, I'm not getting the height to change or seeing the new class in the Styles panel, only in the Elements panel in the browser console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define a CSS selector inside another one with just vanilla CSS, you would need a pre-processor like SASS.

With CSS you can specify properties for when an element has only .lower-container or when it has both. That will be the equivalent of what you were trying to accomplish in your original code.

```
.lower-container {
   height: 46vh;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   ...
}

.lower-container.lower-full {
    height: 92vh;
}
```

If you are using SCSS files already then you are using the incorrect syntax

```
.lower-container {
    height: 46vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    ...

    &.lower-full {
        height: 92vh;
   }
}
```

Edit based on newest edit: Code should look like this:

```
.lower-container {
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 92vw;
//    height: 46vh; <--- no height defined

/* nested for adding classes to change position and height of lower-container */
    &.lower-full {
      height: 92vh;
      top: 0;
    }

    &.lower-mid {
      height: 46vh;
      top: 46vh;
    }

    &.lower-closed {
      height: 1vh;
      top: 91vh;
    }
}
```

Comment: More info on multiple class selectors https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Comment: Yes, sorry I am using scss files and SASS. I'm not getting the new class to appear in the Styles panel in the browser console.

Comment: I added the SCSS solution on my answer, you are using the incorrect syntax for nesting selectors

Comment: Great! Let me try it. So, will the new selector added change/override the height when added to the list ? Also, when I remove the nested selector, will the height return to the original?

Comment: Yes, that is how it will work.

Comment: For some reason I'm still not getting it right... added more code with the new version

Comment: You are still doing it wrong, look at the difference between my selector and yours. You are doing ".lower-container.lower-full" when I am doing "&.lower-full". You can either do ".lower-container.lower-full" as its own "outer" selector or you can do  "&.lower-full" as a "nested" selector.

Comment: I edited my answer with your newest code.

Comment: Haha yes thank you. I'm using & and it is working! Still curious why the difference in the two panels though.

Comment: The difference is because you are adding the class lower-mid then the html will show it on elements panel, but you were not defining any styles for lower-mid (because your css syntax was incorrect) so it would not show on the styles panel. Basically it was a class with no styles defined.